# does wechat share email or phoneid to service provider?

Tags: wechat

I am looking to integrate WeChat in my application as sing up option, but first I wanted to confirm whether WeChat shares email/phoneid of the logged-in user.

Thanks,

Comment: You should probably check their docs & policy

Answer (score 1):

No email/phoneid.

Wechat will give you the openid which helps you confirm users.
So you can save the openid to continue your bussines.

If you have more than one apps in wechat system.You can sign up the wechat development platform to get unionid which confirm users in different apps includes websites, apps, miniprograms, wechat official accounts or wechat Third platforms.

If your company is in China and has authentication in China,you can get the phonenumber.